# Highcharts not working when pass the javascript variable as hightcharts series data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i'm using highstock charts for my website,my issue was it did not work when passing a javascript variable as a series data and working fine by just copy and pase the data string to as a series data

i tried the below

```
function myval() {


    var gtdata=$("#hidgdata").val();  // value of gtdata - [[1421732101000,115],[1421732401000,16],[1421732701000,3],[1421733001000,23],[1421733301000,21],[1421733601000,38],[1421733901000,11],[1421734201000,6],[1421734501000,17],[1421734802000,5],[1421735101000,4],[1421735401000,4],[1421735701000,15],[1421736002000,9],[1421736301000,14],[1421736601000,11],[1421736901000,7],[1421737201000,16],[1421737501000,8],[1421737801000,6],[1421738101000,22],[1421738401000,9],[1421738701000,20]]


            $('#'+myvar).highcharts('StockChart', {


       chart: {
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderRadius: 10,
            height:150
        }, 
        .
        .
        .
        .
         series : [{
                            name : 'value',
                            type:'area',
            data :gtdata,
         .
         .
         .
```

it's not working with above code but working fine when i placed values directly to series data as like `data:[[1421732101000,115],[1421732401000,16],[1421732701000,3].....`, please help me, thanks

Comment: `[[1421732101000,115],[1421732401000,16],[1421732701000,3]` this is my data type, here `1421732101000-unix timestamp` and `115-value`

Comment: What error do you get on console?

Answer (score 2):

`$("#hidgdata").val()` returns a string format, try to parse it into an array.

```
var gtdata = [];
gtdata = JSON.parse($("#hidgdata").val());
```

Comment: it's throwing this error 
`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: already my data in this format `[[1421732101000,115],[1421732401000,16],[1421732701000,3]]`,so

Comment: Execute a `console.log(getdata);` after having assigned the value and check the result.